# Polylang условие

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, polylang

Как в плагине Polylang сделать так чтобы запись опубликовался только тогда когда заполниться контент на всех языках,

Comment: такого из коробки нет в плагинах переводов, насколько мне известно. Можно не публиковать запись на конкретном языке перевода, пока перевод не завершён, но не публиковать саму запись - вряд ли возможно. Только кастомным кодом.

Answer (score 1):

Такого функционала у них нет, но можно получить пост из других языков с помощью SQL-запроса. Связь постов между собой это термины из таксономии *post_translations* в description лежат id постов, а в поле count кол-во перевод:

```
global $wpdb;
$count_translates = $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT count FROM ' . $wpdb->term_taxonomy . ' WHERE taxonomy = "post_translations" AND description LIKE "%i:' . $post_id . ';%"' );
$count_lagnuages = $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT COUNT() FROM ' . $wpdb->term_taxonomy . ' WHERE taxonomy = "language"' );
if ( $count_translates === $count_lagnuages ) {
    ...
}
```

или с помощью функции `pll_get_post( $post_id, $slug = '' )`

Документация:
https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference/